# Add custom data / attributes to button in Android

Tags: android, android-button

What I am doing right now is to pull some data from an API and for each item in the response, I inflate the layout and add another item to the layout.

What I want is to have an "add to favorites" button, which will add the current item in an SQLite database. I've already created the DAO stuff and the DB handling, but there's one thing that bugs me.

When I click the button, I can't tell which item ID's button has been clicked. I'm normally a web developer and on the web, a button can have `data-xxx="yyy"` attributes, where `xxx` and `yyy` are what ever the developer wants.

Is this possible in Android? I have another solution, but it's more like a "hack": create a hidden TextView that holds my item's ID, and get the `onClick` event to check that TextView (the one that is a sibling to the button). Any other ideas?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> When I click the button, I can't tell which item ID's button has been
>   clicked

You can add a piece of arbitrary data to any `View` by using the `setTag()` method. When you inflate the layout for a new item, get the id of that item and set it as the tag for the `Button` in the newly inflated layout corresponding to that item. You'll be able then, in the `OnClickListener` for the `Button`, to retrieve the tag(the id in your case) with the `getTag()` method and happily insert it in the database.

Comment: `setTag`! That's just what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: but,  if I need more than one tag !?

Comment: @FranciscoCorralesMorales The `setTag()` method takes an object that could be anything. This includes a custom wrapper class which could hold all the data you want as a tag in its member fields.

Comment: @FranciscoCorralesMorales setTag() and getTag() optionally accept an integer key. So you can easily store multiple objects per Button.